# What would need to change for supersonic airliners to be the norm?

Tags: supersonic

I know that supersonic airliners have never been widespread, by reason of [cost](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3756/128), [engine technology, aerodynamics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11948/128). Yet can these difficulties be overcome within the next 20 years?

I know of Concorde's retirement and [ongoing attempts at Supersonic Business Jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_business_jet).

Comment: This looks like a dupe of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46470/62), but I can't mark it as such because it has no answers; it was closed as a dupe of other questions, including [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29204/62).

Comment: @Dave Please go ahead and edit my question with your notes!

Comment: @Pondlife if anyone feels strongly about it, we mods can close it as dupe of questions that are dupes themselves. Ping me in chat if you wish

Comment: @Federico Thanks for the info, that's good to know! I don't feel that strongly about it myself, so unless there's a clear consensus I'm not in a hurry to close it.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal if it does not end up closed in the next 24 hours i may add an answer but im going to refrain from editing the question as it is a dupe as it stands but is clear on what you are asking.

Comment: Unlimited money, unlimited oil, and zero care for the environment should do it. [/sarcasm]